# Unable to remove a directory

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, suse

I'm using SUSE and I'm trying to delete an empty directory

When I use `ls -la` it shows that that it contains `.fuse_hidden0000001700000010` with `rw` for owner (that's me not root).

I cannot delete this directory with `rm -fr` or `rm -Rf`.

I tried `chmod 777 directory` and `chown root directory`, `rm -f .fuse_hidden0000001700000010` but I am always unable to delete the file or the directory.

I would like a solution that doesn't require a reboot or using rescue mode.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for, http://serverfault.com/questions/478558/how-to-delete-fuse-hidden-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the filename explicitly, dot included. For instance, rm .fuse* (if you want to include all files beginning with ".fuse"

Comment: the file .fuse----- is always here,